# Git diff parse in shell script

Tags: git, bash, shell, grep, ubuntu-12.04

```
git diff

diff --git a/lids b/lids
index 1191247..2b2f2e1 100644
--- a/lids
+++ b/lids
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 1
-2
+3


git diffdiff --git a/lids b/lids
index 1191247..2b2f2e1 100644
--- a/lids
+++ b/lids
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 1
~
-2
+3
~
```

I need only -2 and +3 
How to do that using grep or shell script?

Comment: It seems that you wanted to ask that you do not want any __context__ for `diff` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output into

```
grep '^[+-][0-9]'
```

So:

```
diff --git a/lids b/lids | grep '^[+-][0-9]'
```